# Windows hibernation not restoring state after booting into another system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, windows-11, hibernate

I have a dualboot of Win11 and Ubuntu on my machine. To quickly switch between, I hibernated Windows, powered on the pc, and got greeted with GRUB. I selected Ubuntu, worked in it, and restarted and selected Windows. But after I boot into windows, there's a new boot instead of the saved state? How to make it save the state until particularly Windows is booted?

Comment: Try disabling Fast Boot in Windows.

Comment: @harrymc It's already disabled. Power > Power button actions > Enable Fast Boot (recommended): Disabled

Comment: Are you booting into Windows from GRUB or directly from the firmware boot menu? Disabling Fast Boot sounds like the opposite of a solution here.

Comment: @user1686 Through GRUB. I don't think that the firmware boot menu can list two OSes on the same disk.

Comment: It can though. If you're using Windows 11, most likely you have it installed in UEFI mode – and the ability to list two OSes on the same disk has been a core feature of EFI since day one, even before it became "UEFI". (Hence the question.) Check your firmware boot menu – does it show any "named" entry (such as "Windows Boot Manager") or only "HDD disk 1" type entries? And if it does show Windows there, does the problem remain if you select that option directly?

Comment: @user1686 The boot menu shows “ubuntu” and “Windows Boot Manager”. And yes, I hibernate, boot Ubuntu, reboot and go into Windows, state restored. But, that's too complicated, I need to spam F11 (or F10, I don't really know), and select the OS there. Is there a way to do that through GRUB or someway use Boot Menu by default when starting? My firmware is MSI Click BIOS 5.

Comment: It's probably fixable even for GRUB – I only vaguely remember this now, but I believe GRUB had two ways of booting Windows (both in BIOS and UEFI environments): it could either start Windows Boot Manager (Bootmgr/Bootmgfw.efi) in the normal way, or it could bypass Bootmgr and attempt to boot the Windows kernel directly. I suspect it's doing the latter and bypassing the "resume from hibernation" part as well. I don't know how to convince it to use the regular method though.

Comment: @user1686 I don't think so. It states Windows Boot Manager, which probably goes to Bootmgr/Bootmgfw.efi. Is there a way to see the GRUB configuration particularly about that? P.S it could be. probably bootmgr decides whether to call winload.exe (boot from scratch), or winresume.exe (restore state).

Comment: Look at the generated /boot/grub/grub.cfg, find the menuitem{} with that name, check whether it calls "bootmgfw.efi" or something else.

Comment: @user1686 I need `root`, right?

Comment: Usually not, but it depends on whether your distro makes /boot root-only or not. On the second thought, you could also press `e` within GRUB to "edit" the highlighted menu entry.

Comment: @user1686 Here's what i found in grub.cfg about Windows: https://pastebin.com/qgbzTEAn